# How to create a function (Iteration/Recursion) to run over a dictionary of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion, dictionary, iteration

I have a Python dictionary of lists like this one:

```
d = {'A': [(4, 4, 3), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
     'B': [(2, 1, 2), [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
     'C': [(4, 1, 1), [2, 4, 1, 2, 4]]}
```

I need to create a formula that accesses the elements of the dictionary and, for every value `[t, l]`:

- Calculates the mean of `t` (let's call this `m`);
- Takes a random sample `s`, with replacement and of length `len(t)`, from `l`;
- Compares `m` with the mean of `s` - `True` if `m` is greater than the mean of `s`, `False` otherwise;
- Repeats this process 10,000 times
- Returns the percentage of times `m` is greater than the mean of `s`.

The output should look like:

```
In [16]: test(d)   
Out[16]: {'A': 0.5, 'B': 0.9, 'C': 0.4}
```

I think I'm not that far from an answer, this is what I have tried:

```
def test(dict):
    def mean_diff(dict):
        for k, (v0, v1) in dict.iteritems():
            m = np.mean(v0) > (np.mean(npr.choice(v1, size=(1, len(v0)), replace=True)))
            return ({k: m})
    for k, (v0, v1) in dict.iteritems():
        bootstrap = np.array([means_diff(dict) for _ in range(10000)])
        rank = float(np.sum(bootstrap))/10000
        return ({k: rank})
```

However, I got:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a list comprehension that essentially selects a random value and compares it to the mean. This will produce a list of True/False. If you take the mean of that, it will be averaging a list of 1's and 0's, so it will give you the aggregate probability.

```
import numpy as np

d = {'A': [(4, 4, 3), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
     'B': [(2, 1, 2), [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]],
     'C': [(4, 1, 1), [2, 4, 1, 2, 4]]}

def makeRanks(d):
    rankDict = {}
    for key in d:
        tup = d[key][0]
        mean = np.mean(tup)
        l = d[key][1]
        rank = np.mean([mean > np.mean(np.random.choice(l,len(tup))) for _ in range(10000)])
        rankDict[key] = rank
    return rankDict
```

Testing

```
>>> makeRanks(d)
{'C': 0.15529999999999999, 'A': 0.72130000000000005, 'B': 0.031899999999999998}
```

Comment: Note that you should be comparing to the mean of a `len(tup)`-length `sample`: *"The length of this random sample is the same as the length of the first value of the tuple."*

Comment: If I understood the original question, I think the way I wrote it is correct. The deterministic answer to this question would produce `{'A': 0.6, 'B': 0.2, 'C': 0.2}`, which is relatively close to the probabilistic answer the above code produces.

Comment: @Cyber If the samples are taken with replacement, there is a chance you select (1, 1, 1)

Comment: Gotcha! Okay I understand the problem now, I edited my code accordingly.